# How to display the exact p-values instead of < 0.001***?

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I conducted a logistic regression and multiple comparison

```
library(lme4)
model < glmer(y ~ Genger + Age + subject +
    (1 | ParticipantID), data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

library(multcomp)
multicomp<-glht(model,mcp(Behavior="Tukey"))
summary(multicomp)
```

The output:

```
                              Estimate  Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
subject2 - subject1 ==  0 -2.19503726  0.66179761 -2.89596  < 0.001 ***
```

I want to display the exact p-values instead of `< 0.001***` . What should I do?

I tried

```
options(digits=10)
```

but the output did not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it like this:

```
library(lme4)
data(Orthodont,package="nlme")
model <-lmer(distance ~ Sex + age + (age|Subject), data=Orthodont)

library(multcomp)
multicomp<-glht(model, mcp(Sex = "Tukey"))
res <- summary(multicomp)

print(res)
#                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
#Female - Male == 0  -2.1454     0.7575  -2.832  0.00462 **


coeftable <- do.call(cbind, res$test[c("coefficients", "sigma", "tstat", "pvalues")])
colnames(coeftable) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "z value", "Pr(>|z|)")

printCoefmat(coeftable) 

#more digits (but still some protection against showing more digits than meaningful)
printCoefmat(coeftable, digits = 10) 

#no protection
print(coeftable)

#even more digits
options(digits = 20)
print(coeftable)
```

However, there is a reason why the exact p-value isn't printed. It is easily impacted by [precision of floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) and also based on statistical assumptions which introduce uncertainty because they don't hold exactly. The `multcomp` developers are trying to protect you against interpreting meaningless numbers.

Comment: It's not just floating-point precision; the p-values are also based on various assumptions that don't hold, the most important of which is that you have an arbitrarily large amount of data (but also linearity, independence, etc etc )